# Difference between CLASS and By processing in SAS STAT Procs?

Tags: sas

I am wondering if there is any major difference between using class or by statements in SAS STAT procs.  Take proc means for example.  Suppose we have 2 group/categorical variables, x1 and x2.  I want to compute summary statistics for a variable (x3) for each level combination of x1 and x2.
For example, using `class x1 x2` gives me summary stats for x3 at x2=1 at x1=1 and then summary stats for x3 at x2=2 at x1=1, and so on.
Below is example output.

```
x1=1 x2=1 x3 mean std
     x2=2 x3 mean std
x1=2 x2=1 x3 mean std
...
```

If I use `by x1 x2` I get

```
x1=1 x2=1
x3 mean std
(new page)
x1=1 x2=2
x3 mean std
(new page)
....
```

If I use `class x1` and `by x2` I get

```
x1=1
x2=1 x3 mean std
x2=2 x3 mean std
x1=2
x2=1 x3 mean std
x2=2 x3 mean std
......
```

This is some sample data

```
x1 x2 x3
1  1  3
1  1  4
1  2  6
1  2  2
2  1  5
2  1  1
2  2  2
2  2  6
3  1  10
3  1  2
3  2  1
3  2  8
```

The best I can tell, there is no difference in output, except the manner in which it is displayed.  My example may be too simplistic to show any differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond what Bob noted (the sorting requirement), which is certainly important, there are differences in how percentages are calculated.  In PROC TABULATE, for example, a CLASS variable must be on a page, row, or column dimension, while BY supersedes that; `PCTN` and `PCTSUM` work across all class variables (as opposed to `ROWPCTN` wetc.), which is important because `PCTN` and `PCTSUM` can be used with denominator definitions, while `ROWPCTN` etc cannot.

Some STAT procs also evaluate the differences between class groups, while BY variables again supersede that - PROC TTEST for example compares values between different values of the CLASS variables, while BY groups would simply create different strata inside which the comparisons are performed.

Finally, I would encourage you to use them correctly in terms of showing what you intend for them to show.  BY variables should denote separate strata, where the analysis is performed on each strata independently.  CLASS variables should denote different groupings of the data in the same stratum. This is very helpful for creating self documenting code, as if you are careful to be consistent, it is easier to read your code and understand the data.

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference is that a `BY` statement requires the SAS data set be sorted by the listed variables.  Stats are collected and reported in the BY-groups. If you use a `CLASS` statement, the SAS dataset does not need to be sorted; all the stats are collected in memory and reported at the end of the procedure.

There are also subtle differences in the generated report output, as you've noticed.